# Change "Total Editing Time" in microsoft word using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

complete novice here.
I have tried a few different ways to change a ms word document property but I can't seem to get it to work. I'm trying to re-make one of my documents that I was working on but it became corrupt - manually adding back all the different properties etc.

I tried this among some others I already forgot.

```
Sub test_getProperties()
    updateThisDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties "Total Editing Time", "34500", msoPropertyTypeNumber     
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub setproperties()
BuiltInDocumentProperties("Total Editing Time").Value = 34500
End Sub
```

and

```
Sub WriteDocumentProperties()
    Dim objBuiltDocProp As Object
    
    Set objBuiltDocProp = ThisWorkbook.BuiltInDocumentProperties
    
    objBuiltDocProp("Total Editing Time") = 35000

End Sub
```

Which just keep giving me '424' - being a novice I don't know how to fix it, help pls

Comment: Seems like it's either read-only and that isn't listed anywhere or the setter in `.value` is messed up in the underlying code.

Comment: Note that "total editing time" does not really mean editing time. It means time open on the computer, whether or not the document has the focus or whether there is actually a person at the keyboard.

Comment: Cross-posted at: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?68857-Setting-quot-Total-Editing-Time-quot-property-using-VBA-in-MS-Word. For cross-posting etiquette, please read: http://www.excelguru.ca/content.php?184

Answer (score 5):

Simple rule of thumb: if a property can't be edited in the UI, it can't be edited in VBA either.

However, you can directly edit the xml. If you have 7-Zip installed you can use it to open the document archive. The file you need is `app.xml` which is in the `docProps` folder. You'll find a property called `TotalTime` the value for which is in minutes.

Comment: I can't believe this actually works! Upvoted, thank you